# What policy should be applied to load this source type to a DWH?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

Guess we have a claim management app in an enterprise. 
This app have different tables such as:

1. Claim types
2. Claim log
3. Claim table
4. User table
5. User claim relational table

The app allows the user to create new claim types (1), and then an admin could admit this type or delete it. Furthermore, this app allows the claim creation (3), and log it. This also log the ip, and other parameters (2). Finally, we have a user table, because only some users can create claims (4), and a table that stores the claims created per user (5).

All this tables have foreign and primary keys that must be respected for the correct usability of the app.

Now, we want to load this into a DWH. All tables must be truncated and loaded every day because all tables can have new rows, or even deleted rows every day. In this case we have two ways to do this:

- Load every table without FK's and PK's. Then DWH is like a backup because data integrity is checked in the original tables.
- Load tables with PK's and FK's. DWH check also for data integrity, but then ETL process have to erase FK's, and then can truncate table to finally rebuild FK's and load again the table. I do not know if it can create any complication to the database.

What is the correct approach for a DWH when the source ensure the data integrity? Should the DWH checks for data integrity with relational keys, or only store data to create reports and dashboards?

In case of reporting and dashboarding maybe the first option is valid, but what happens if then this data is through a bulk process loaded to another app that have to explode this same relations as the original app?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on the database that you are implementing your data warehouse on. So I will give you an Oracle specific answer. 
In general, the recommendation is the create the PK/FK's, but use `RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE`. This has the effect of creating the meta data that defines the relationships, but without the indexes that are likely un-needed in your DW. The PK/FK relationships allows Oracle to perform a number of optimizations that it otherwise could not.

Comment: And what if the data warehouse uses a PostgreSQL RDBMS?